# Pretty-printing in ghci

Tags: haskell, show, pretty-print, ghci

Is there a way to make ghci use a custom pretty-printing function instead of show for certain types? A more general question: what are the general guidelines to make a library as usable as possible in interactive mode? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify a custom pretty-printing function using the `--interactive-print` flag and naming any function in scope with the type `C a => a -> IO ()` for any constraint `C`. (See [Section 2.4.9](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-interactive-print) of the docs for details.)

```
ghci --interactive-print=MyModule.prettyPrint
```

This means you can specify your own function from your own typeclass. There's no way to do this just for a specific type, but your custom class can always include a fallback instance like

```
instance Show a => PrettyPrint a where prettyPrint = show
```

This will require at least `OverlappingInstances` to work.